# Change text and background on clicks in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a RecyclerView and want to change text and item background when it is clicked. And change it back to the initial state when clicked again. Initial text and background is set by default in XML.

**Please write in comments if you need to see more code.**

---

### WindowAdapter.java

```
public class WindowAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WindowAdapter.WindowViewHolder> {

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Window> windowList;

    public WindowAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Window> windowList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.windowList = windowList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WindowViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
        return new WindowViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WindowViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Window window = windowList.get(position);

        holder.textViewTitle.setText(window.getTitle());
        holder.textViewChecked.setText(window.getCheck());

        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(window.getImage()));
////////////////////////////////////////////////
        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
//////////////////////////////////////
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return windowList.size();
    }

    class WindowViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textViewTitle;
        TextView textViewChecked;

        RelativeLayout parentLayout;

        public WindowViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.window_name);
            textViewChecked = itemView.findViewById(R.id.window_check);
///////////////////////////////////////////
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add if condition e-g, declare a boolean variable isBackgroundChange = false; if(isBackgroundChange){ // change background  isBackgroundChange=false} else { set another background isBackgroundChange=true }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 boolean isBackgroundChange = false;

 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WindowViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Window window = windowList.get(position);

          holder.textViewTitle.setText(window.getTitle());
      //  holder.textViewChecked.setText(window.getCheck());
      //  holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources()
      // .getDrawable(window.getImage()));

        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!isBackgroundChange){
            holder.textViewChecked.setText("Button Clicked");
            holder.parentLayout.setBackground(....); //set Background for RelativeLayout after button clicked
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(......); // set the image which you want to show after button clicked.
            isBackgroundChange = true;
            }else{
            holder.parentLayout.setBackground(....); // set previous background for realtiveLayout.
            holder.textViewChecked.setText("Button Clicked again ");
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(.....); // set the previous image.
            isBackgroundChange = false;

            }

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: But how to change Relative layout background color on click?

Comment: Where should I write it (RelativeLayout layout = ...)?

Comment: holder.parentLayout.setBackground(...); only this line write inside If body and elsy body

Comment: setBackgroundColor helped me :)

Comment: It's used for textView and you were asking for relativeLayout that's why I mentioned code regarding relative layout. Happy to help you. If my answer helps you please vote up thanks best of luck!

Comment: This answer is wrong since it doesn't take into account `ViewHolder` recycling at all (background will get messed up once view is clicked and you begin scrolling).

Comment: I just give him/her idea, she can remove  holder.textViewChecked.setText(window.getCheck());................
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources()
        .getDrawable(window.getImage()));........ from onBindViewHOlder and left them in If and else body.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to say getText() and getBackackground() on the current item in holder and save it to some temp variables, use a boolean to keep track if it has already been clicked and use that to set it back to the original.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the selected item outside the `ViewHolder` so it doesn't get lost during scroll.

Create a field like `private Window selectedWindow;` within your adapter.

It's advised to have your `onClickListener` initialized only once in ViewHolders constructor so you don't keep allocating objects during scroll.

Then inside your onClick listener use `windowList.get(getAdapterPosition())` to obtain item this `ViewHolder` is currently bound to. Store this item as `selectedWindow` and make clicked `ViewHolder` views selected (or, if this window is the selected one, set the field to null and clear selection).

Inside your `onBindViewHolder` you must add a check if `window == selectedWindow`. If true, change your `ViewHolder` views into selected state. If false then change your `ViewHolder`into deselected state.